# CMake macro across CMakeLists

Tags: macros, cmake

I have a c++ project which directory structure like below:

```
server/
   code/
      BASE/
         Thread/
         Log/
         Memory/
      Net/
   cmake/
      CMakeList.txt
      BASE/
         CMakeList.txt
      Net/
         CMakeList.txt
```

here is part of /cmake/CMakeList.txt:

```
MACRO(SUBDIRLIST result curdir)
  FILE(GLOB children RELATIVE ${curdir} ${curdir}/*)
  SET(dirlist "")
  FOREACH(child ${children})
    IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${curdir}/${child})
        SET(dirlist ${dirlist} ${child})
    ENDIF()
  ENDFOREACH()
  SET(${result} ${dirlist})
ENDMACRO()

add_subdirectory(Base)
```

then use macro in /cmake/Base/CMakeList.txt:

```
SET(SUBDIR, "")
SUBDIRLIST(SUBDIRS, ${BASE_SRC_DIR})
message("SUBDIRS : " ${SUBDIRS})
```

output:
SUBDIRS :

I check ${dirlist} by output it's value in macro, I get directory list expected,but when message("result " ${result}) after SET(${result} ${dirlist}),I can not get output expected , what's wrong with my CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of minor issues here:

1. In your macro, `SET(dirlist "")` could be just `SET(dirlist)`.  Likewise, `SET(SUBDIR, "")` could be just `SET(SUBDIRS)` (I guess "SUBDIR" is a typo and should be "SUBDIRS".  Also you don't want the comma in the `set` command - probably another typo?)
2. To output the contents of `${result}` in the macro, use `message("result: ${${result}}")`, since you're not appending `${child}` to `result` each time, but to `${result}`.  In your example `${result}` is `SUBDIRS`, so `${${result}}` is `${SUBDIRS}`.
3. When you call `SUBDIRLIST`, don't use a comma between the arguments.
4. When you output the value of `SUBDIRS`, include `${SUBDIRS}` in the quotes, i.e. `message("SUBDIRS: ${SUBDIRS}")` or you'll lose the semi-colon separators.

Other than those, your macro seems fine.